# how are bitshift, bitrotate implemented in circuit?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Can you implement bit shift using only logic operations: and, or, not, xor ? 
Can you use bitshift in a [bitblt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370(VS.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

To implement bitshifts/rotates in circuits: you can build registers from an array of [Flip Flops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29) which in turn you can build e.g. from NAND gates.

In order to implement bit-shifts/rotates you would wire two such registers (or feed back to the same register) by wiring the output of bit 0 to the input of bit 1 etc.

The contents are then transferred on e.g. the next clock rising edge from one array of flip-flops to the other.

Comment: This would only shift by 1.

Comment: That is one of the slowest implementations possible

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a left shift with addition `a + a`. The result of an and/or/not/xor do not depend upon adjacent bits, so you can't use them for bitshifts. In circuit, i'd expect they are hard-coded... You can use bit-shifting for fast hardware multiplication anyway.